# Twitter bootstrap rails simple form formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I'm trying to reformat the simple default devise login screen with twitter bootstrap simple form and I'm having major issues.

[image: screenshot]

Here is my code:

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |form| %>

<%= form.input :email, :autofocus => true %>
<%= form.input :password %>
<%= form.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
<%= form.button :submit, 'Sign in', :class => 'primary'%>
<% end %>

<%= render "links" %>
```

I can get the spacing between the labels and input fields to be correct if I add

```
.form-horizontal .controls {
  margin-left: 160px;
}
```

to my application.css file, but I don't see this anywhere in their sample app here
https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap
and am really confused where the proper formatting is coming from.

I have almost the same code as this guy https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap/issues/6 but his code is older I think.  I am using simple form 2.0.2 and I installed bootstrap with twitter-bootstrap-rails 1.4.3.  I also installed and uninstalled a couple other twitter bootstrap gems if theres any chance that's messing things up.

Edit: here is my produced code if that helps

### Sign in

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admins/sign_in" class="simple_form form-horizontal" id="new_admin" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="xxx" /></div>

<div class="control-group email optional"><label class="email optional control-label" for="admin_email">Email</label><div class="controls"><input autofocus="autofocus" class="string email optional" id="admin_email" name="admin[email]" size="50" type="email" value="" /></div></div>
<div class="control-group password optional"><label class="password optional control-label" for="admin_password">Password</label><div class="controls"><input class="password optional" id="admin_password" name="admin[password]" size="50" type="password" /></div></div>
<div class="control-group boolean optional"><label class="boolean optional control-label" for="admin_remember_me">Remember me</label><div class="controls"><input name="admin[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0" /><label class="checkbox"><input class="boolean optional" id="admin_remember_me" name="admin[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1" /></label></div></div>
<input class="btn primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign in" />
</form>


<a href="/admins/password/new">Forgot your password?</a><br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow that was painful.  It turns out there is an error in the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/324

If you have this problem I recommend uninstalling that gem and everything associated with it and following these directions http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout?version=3.2#sec-custom_css

to get started.  Summary of link:

1. Install 'bootstrap-sass' gem
2. Add a custom.css.scss file with "@import 'bootstrap';" and you're good to go.